# What's the difference between "editor.insertSpaces" and "editor.tabSize" in settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How are they interpreted differently? I can only see what "editor.tabSize" does, which is the number of spaces that a tab occupies.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the configuration file:

```
{
  // Controls the rendering size of tabs in characters. 
  // If set to auto, the value will be guessed based on the opened file.
  "editor.tabSize": 4,

  // Controls if the editor will insert spaces for tabs. 
  // If set to auto, the value will be guessed based on the opened file.
  "editor.insertSpaces": true
}
```

As you can see `editor.tabSize` sets the size of space occupied when you enter `tab`. While `editor.insertSpaces` configures the stored key code in file.

If `editor.insertSpaces` equals `false` then Visual Studio Code will insert one `#09` character for each `tab`. When you change `editor.tabSize` your existing code **will** change indentation in all lines a  `#09` character is stored.

If `editor.insertSpaces` equals `true` then Visual Studio Code will insert `space` characters for each `tab` instead of `#09` characters. The amount of inserted `spaces` is configured in `editor.tabSize`. When you change `editor.tabSize` your existing code **will not** change indentation since there is no `#09` character being stored in the file. Only new `tab` strokes will be affected by the new value of `editor.tabSize`.

If you and other team members use **only** `tab` for indentation then it is no problem to set `editor.insertSpaces` to false. 
If you and other team members use `space` **or** `tab` for indentation then you should set `editor.insertSpaces` to true. Otherwise your files can look awkward when somebody opens a file with a different value of `editor.insertSpaces`.

Answer (score 3):

**editor.insertSpaces:**
Controls if the editor will insert spaces for tabs. Accepted values:  "auto", true, false. If set to "auto", the value will be guessed when a file is opened.

**editor.tabSize:**
Controls the rendering size of tabs in characters. Accepted values: "auto", 2, 4, 6, etc. If set to "auto", the value will be guessed when a file is opened.