# VSCode: How do you autoformat on save?

Tags: formatting, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, how do you automatically format your source code when the file is saved?

Comment: There are disadvantages with format on save, just want to remind you.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Enable "Format On Save" by setting

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true
```

And since [version **1.49.0**](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_49#_only-format-modified-text) `editor.formatOnSaveMode` has the option `modifications` that will just format the code *you* modified. Great when you change someone else code.

You can also set it just for one specific language:

```
"[python]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true #
},
```

Since version **1.6.1**, Vscode supports "*Format On Save*". It will automatically use a relevant installed formatter extension to format the whole document.

If you are modifying other users code and your team don't standardize a formatter, a nice option also is `"editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modifications",`. Unfortunately, the excellent black formatter does [not support this feature](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/134).

Comment: When formatonSave is active, you should adapt your **delay** parameter if **autosave** is on. Otherwise you get the format function all over the time.

Comment: [More](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32732595/1705829) details about spaces and tabs.

Answer (score 30):

Below are the steps to change the VS Code auto format on save settings:

1. Use [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[p]
2. Type "Preferences"
3. Select "Preferences: Open User Settings"
4. Search for "format"
5. Change "Editor: Format On Save" or "Editor: Format On Paste".

There are also Keyboard Shortcuts for formatting in VS Code. For instance, the default to format selected code should be [Ctrl]+K [Ctrl]+F (type both hotkeys in succession).

Below are the steps to change the auto format hotkey settings:

1. Use [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[p]
2. Type "Keyboard"
3. Select "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts"
4. Search for "format"
5. Change "Format Selection" or "Format Document".

Answer (score 9):

Go to **/.vscode/settings.json** file and paste below code

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
}
```

It will format your code on save.

Answer (score 2):

settings.json:

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modifications",
"editor.formatOnType": true,
"editor.formatOnPaste": true,
```

"formatOnSaveMode" is important to only format modified code, as **I don't want to touch legacy code**.
If I want to format the whole document, I'll call "Format Document" obviously.

"formatOnType" works after I enter a full stmt (e.g. for CPP, after ';')

Comment: Is this mostly important in a team context where the legacy code is bad and you don't want your hands on it? Or some other reason?