# Why is my Dart code auto-moved to a different line, when I Ctrl+S?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

What happened is that when I move my codes to different lines, and when I CTRL+S, the code automatically get moved to a different line.

[image]

What setting in VS Code is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have format on save.

You need to go to VS Code settings and search `formatOnSave` and turn it off

Answer (score 2):

check if the "auto format on save" option is on: [VSCode: How do you autoformat on save?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606758/vscode-how-do-you-autoformat-on-save/50606759)

you can also go into the dart plugin's preferences in vscode and change the line length at which formatting the code will auto-wrap it. You can make it however long you want. Just go into settings and search "Dart: Line Length"

Answer (score 0):

For me, I went to the dart extension setting, there is an option of **Dart: Enable SDK Formatter**. It should be the problem I guess because when I disabled it, everything started working fine.

We can directly search for **Dart: Enable SDK Formatter** in VS Code settings.

Comment: This will disable the dart formatter completely. OP just doesn't want it to run on save.