# Why does VS Code mark closing HTML tags with space between the tag name and the right angle bracket as invalid?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, themes, tailwind-css

When I added an SVG to my footer, elements after the SVG (including the closing tag of the SVG) turned red. Is there a problem with the code? Prettier seems to work fine.

The issue can be reproduced minimally like this:

```html
<svg></svg
>
```

I don't see this issue on all colour themes. One that I do see it on is the Dark+ theme.

[image]

Only after deleting the SVG do the elements revert to their original colour.

I'm on VS Code 1.78, but I'm not sure if that detail is relevant here.

Comment: loosly related but probably not actually related: [custom 'html' tags are in red color #56467](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/56467)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's red because you forgot to close the `svg` tag

Here's how should be: `</g></svg>`

--- Edited

It's because your close tag is one line down; if you move close to the `svg`, it should be fixed.

You also can change your settings on VS Code to format your code when you save the file, to avoid this issue in the future.

Here's a quick reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50606759/2092969

Comment: Thank you, VScode's prettier formats it a little weird

Comment: they do close it on the next line, and doing so is legal HTML.

Comment: You're right, it's just in the wrong place @user

Comment: @ViniciusCainelli see my answer for a better explanation of what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` command in the command palette to see what's going on.

For the tags that are highlighted normally, I see these TextMate scopes:

```
entity.name.tag.html
meta.tag.object.svg.path.start.html
meta.element.object.svg.path.html
meta.element.structure.svg.g.html
meta.element.structure.svg.html
text.html.derivative
```

For the differently coloured ones, I see these TextMate scopes:

```
invalid.illegal.unrecognized-tag.html
entity.name.tag.html
meta.tag.other.svg.html
meta.element.structure.svg.html
text.html.derivative
```

But if you look at the HTML spec, it says what you've written with a newline and spaces separating the tag name in the closing tag and its closing angle bracket is legal HTML.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#end-tags says:

> 4. After the tag name, there may be one or more ASCII whitespace.

https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-whitespace says:

> **ASCII whitespace** is U+0009 TAB, U+000A LF, U+000C FF, U+000D CR, or U+0020 SPACE.

Also related: [Is whitespace allowed within XML/HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3314535/11107541).

So this seems like a bug with [VS Code's builtin HTML TextMate grammar](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/html/syntaxes/html.tmLanguage.json).

Actually, if you google "`github vscode issues html closing tag space between tag name and angle bracket invalid`" and scroll down a bit, you'll find [svg tag in HTML mode incorrectly marked invalid when closing tag spans more than one line #124215](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/124215), which covers exactly this issue, and is closed pointing upstream to [Incorrect HTML Syntax highlighting on SVG with Line break #101](https://github.com/textmate/html.tmbundle/issues/101). You can give the issue a thumbs up to show support for getting it fixed, and subscribe to it to get notified of discussion and progress (but please avoid making noisy "me too" comments).

The reason you don't see this behaviour for all colour themes is because some themes set their highlighting for "invalid" tags to be coloured the same as valid tags, or just don't make the colour difference apparent enough for it to be noticeable, or maybe they're just not setting it and it's defaulting to something that looks similar to the colour they chose for valid tags.

Funnily, it looks like [Stack Exchange's syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/997587) (which uses highlight.js) fails to detect that this is valid HTML as well.